# Acessing and using a cached var for LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, caching, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use a cached variable for LINQ and I'm having issues accessing the cached variable in order to run further select LINQ statements.

Code:

```
string cachedsearchname = "MyCachedVar";
var output = HttpContext.Cache[cachedsearchname];

if (output == null)
{
    output = (from l in db.vwMyView select l)
    HttpContext.Cache.Insert(cachedsearchname, output);
}

var output2 = (List<vwMyView>)HttpContext.Cache[cachedsearchname];
```

The last line throws the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entitiy.Infrastracture.DbQuery'1[vwMyView]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[vwMyView]'

My goal would be to run:

```
if (PassedQuerystring.Contains("MyRequestedOption")
{
    output = (from m in output2 where m.myrequestedoption
                                       .Contains("MyRequestedOption")
                                       select m)
}
```

Challenge is I don't want to convert `ToList()` yet as the cached result is quite large.

Any input much appreciated.

Comment: Why not throw a `ToList` on the end of the query?  That would cache the data and not the query.

Comment: Why do you want to cache it, if not so that the "quite large" results are only obtained once?

Comment: Adding ToList() adds a huge time expense when running and yes - I want to cache in order to do this once so next time its called, no need to hit the db. (Performance reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve from the cache, you need to cast to the same datatype that went into the cache.

Comment: Thanks Nick - would have preferred this:                                                    
 var output2 = HttpContext.Cache[cachedsearchname]; but then I cannot use LINQ to run select on it

Comment: You can cast it back to the type shown in your error message and use it exactly as you want.